# Apache Camel - How doneFileName Works

Tags: apache-camel

**source_dir** Have files like: ABC_02022018_162301.CSV, ABC_02022018_231801.CSV, controlFile

```
<route id="Test">
  <from uri="file:source_dir?include=ABC_.*\.CSV&amp;doneFileName=controlFile&amp;delete=true&amp;readLock=changed&amp;readLockTimeout=20000&amp;readLockCheckInterval=5000&amp;eadLockMinLength=0"/>
<log message="${file:name}"/>
**destination directory **
</route>
```

I am looking here is, route has to check controlFile for every main file. If any main file doesn't have control file, main file shouldn't move from source folder.

In my above code, camel only once checking for control file existence in source folder and moving all the files to destination folder. Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) (section 'Using 'done' Files'), in order to have one doneFile per main file you need to specify dynamic doneFile names:

> it is more common to have one done file per target file. This means
> there is a 1:1 correlation. To do this you must use dynamic
> placeholders in the doneFileName option. Currently Camel supports the
> following two dynamic tokens: file:name and file:name.noext which must
> be enclosed in ${}

if you don't, then Camel will consume all files and then delete the doneFile unless `noop=true`

Comment: Thanks for your time codebrane. I do agree with you, but with the static name for doneFileName is working in Windows OS. That's where i got confused, why it is not working in UNIX OS.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: if you define doneFileName dynamically like this "doneFileName=${file:name.noext}.trig" then each file you want to transfer must have a copy with .trig extension.
If you define doneFileName statically like "doneFileName=files.trig" then every file will be moved when files.trig appears.

So you have to think of a unique doneFileName for each file instead of "controlFile" and set it dynamically. Easiest way is to use the actual fileName and add some extension.

### Examples:

Imagine this files: file1.txt, file2.txt
and this route from:

```
from("ftp://admin@localhost/from?password=admin"
        + "&fileName=${file:name}"
        + "&doneFileName=${file:name.noext}.done")
```

In this case file1.txt will be moved only if file1.done is also present in the same folder. file2.txt will be moved only if file2.done is also present in the same folder.

Now imagine this route:

```
from("ftp://admin@localhost/from?password=admin"
        + "&fileName=${file:name}"
        + "&doneFileName=controlFile");
```

In this case both files file1.txt and file2.txt will be moved when files.done file is present in the same folder.